# Can't run flutter project on android device with IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, flutter, intellij-idea

My operating system is Pop!_OS 20.10. I am simply trying to run a flutter project, which I created on IntelliJ, on my android device using IntelliJ IDEA. The build is being completed without any errors but when running the app, it says that my JAVA_HOME variable is set to an invalid directory:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Mi A2 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /app/extra/idea-IU/jre64

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

SDKs installed on my platform settings are openjdk-15.0.2, corretto-1.8 and Android API 30 Platform. I didn't manually altered any environment variables before getting this error. After this, I tried to add JAVA_HOME variable to `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/environment` files to point my JDK installation folder like this:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
```

and also tried with my current java installation:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

but no luck. I did a lot of research and really don't know what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

1 - Your flutter sdk is may be some old version. Run `flutter upgrade` to update your flutter sdk.

2 - You might not have installed JDK or the JDK Path is not set in Environment Variables.

Comment: My flutter sdk is up to date. It is working perfectly with Android Studio. This problem occurs only on IntelliJ. JDK is installed and set correctly in Environment Variables because I can build & run projects without using Gradle. I guess I will stick with Android Studio for now. Thanks for your response.